# The complement of a first category set in X is a set of second category.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category

Let X be a complete metric space. Then the complement of a first category set in X is a set of second category in X.

What is explain in my class is "if the complement of a first category set is a set of first category, then the entire space would be countable unions of nowhere dense sets, which is not the case in complete metric space." Please explain it.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, $X$ must be non-empty for the claim as stated to be true. Instead of giving you the answer, here is a situation that if you understand it, and the definition of first and second category, then you'll understand your situation too.

Suppose that $S$ is an uncountable set. Then if $T$ is a countable subset of $S$, then $S\setminus T$ must be uncountable. Why? since the union of two countable sets is countable, so if both $T$ and $S\setminus T$ were countable, then $S$, their union, would be countable too.

So, back to your (non-empty!) complete metric space $X$. Do you know why $X$ is of second category? Can you show that the union of two first category spaces is of first category?